# Is it possible to store an HTML input class into a PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an html form and some php and a little bit of javascript. The form has two input tags. Both input tags have class attributes. I would like to 'store' the class value inside a PHP variable so I can echo after clicking submit.

I've tried integrating javascript with the first php variable ($firstclass) and failed to get it working even as an alert(). I really don't want to alert the class value but figured this would help find the solution.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input1" class="hidden_class_1">
    <input type="text" name="input2" class="hidden_class_2">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

$firstclass = ""; //hidden_class_1
$secondclass = ""; //hidden_class_2

$firstclass = "<script type=\"application/javascript\">alert(('this.className').attr('class'))</script>";

$secondclass = ""; //ideally hidden_class_2

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "<h2>First Input Class Value: ".$firstclass."</h2>";
    echo "<h2>Second Input Class Value: ".$secondclass."</h2>";
}
```

I expect the output to be as follows;

### First Input Class Value: hidden_class_1

### Second Input Class Value: hidden_class_2

Comment: use ajax - don't mix PHP and JS

Comment: interesting, could you provide an example?

Comment: Only if you're ok with using jQuery - I don't know vanilla JS equiv. of the needed functions

Comment: Yes, I'm ok with using jQuery, would be very grateful if you could provide a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "easiest" way would be to use AJAX/XHR and send the classes to the PHP script.

```
<form id="ajaxform" action="path/to/script.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="input1" class="hidden_class_1">
  <input type="text" name="input2" class="hidden_class_2">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

For example, using jQuery:

```
const $form = $('#ajaxform');

function onSuccess (response) {
  console.log('Successfully submitted the form');
  console.log('Server responded with', response);
}

function onFailure (jqXhr, status) {
  console.log('Ooops, something went wrong!');
  console.log('Server sent status code', status);
}

$form.on('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault(); // suppress the reload

  const $input1 = $form.find('[name=input1]');
  const $input2 = $form.find('[name=input2]');

  $.ajax({
    method: $form.prop('method').toUpperCase(),
    url: $form.prop('action'),
    data: {
      input1Value: $input1.val(),
      input2Value: $input2.val(),
      input1Class: $input1.prop('className'),
      input2Class: $input2.prop('className')
    }
  }).
  done(onSuccess).
  fail(onFailure);
});
```

Inside you PHP, you'd use `$_POST` (or `$_REQUEST`) to grab the values which have been sent:

```
$input1_value = $_POST['input1Value'];
$input2_value = $_POST['input2Value'];
$input1_class = $_POST['input1Class'];
$input2_class = $_POST['input2Class'];

# do what you want with the variables
```

Note that you have to handle the server's response inside the `onSuccess` function. Usually, people use JSON to model a response from the server. You can use PHP's build-in `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions for it. For example, your PHP script could answer with:

```
$input1_value = $_POST['input1Value'];
$input2_value = $_POST['input2Value'];
$input1_class = $_POST['input1Class'];
$input2_class = $_POST['input2Class'];

# do what you want to do with the variables, then

$response = array(
  'ok' => true,
  'message' => 'PHP says "Thanks" for the information'
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
die;
```

Inside the `onSuccess` function, you'd then for example:

```
function onSuccess (response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    console.log('Submitted, and all values where OK');
    console.log(response.message);
    return; // opt-out early, no need for "else" keyword
  }
  console.log('Submitted, but something went wrong');
  console.log(response.message);
}
```